# How to add image between tableview and cell

Tags: tableview, cell, uitableview

how can i add image between tableview and cell? i mean,this image should be under the cell but below the tableview.I add an image but it is not constant when scroll changes its location changes as cell.I want a constant image in tableview,also I add an image self.view but when cell came,image is below of cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing. As I understand you want to add image as a background of UITableview and that image will not be affected by the scrolling of your table.

**Solution** : Set clear background color to your cell and add your image as a background of your Tableview like mentioned below.

**In ViewDidLoad add following Code**

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone.jpg"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

**Add following method to clear the background color of UITableViewCell.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: yeah with a little changes it worked what i looked was "self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;" thanks @pratik Mistry!

UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoend.png"]]; UIView * logoView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.checkinsTable.frame.size.width, self.checkinsTable.frame.size.height)]; [logoView addSubview:tempImageView]; tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(55, 100, 50, 50); self.checkinsTable.backgroundView = logoView;